# Is there a function to find sustained sequences within lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have data that represents a cyclist’s power output in 1-second intervals, sampled while the cyclist was working to a prescribed training regime.

I want to find sequences within that data where the cyclist sustained a power output (plus or minus a certain percentage threshold) for fixed lengths of time. So:

$\qquad $120W ± 5W for 30s or more
$\qquad $125W ± 5W for 30s or more
$\qquad $...
$\qquad $120W ± 5W for 60s or more
$\qquad $125W ± 5W for 60s or more

And so on. Time sequences do not need to align to fixed intervals, so a sequence could start at any second. I am NOT looking for moving averages; the cyclist must maintain the target range for the sequence to qualify.

I could roll my own function to do this. But is there one already in the Wolfram language?

Comment: You can simply use [`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html) together with `MinMax`. After that, simply look for values of `{115,125}` or similar

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, use [`MovingMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MovingMap.html) and [`MinMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html):

```
SeedRandom[99]
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[.5], {0, 100}]

DateListPlot@data
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
minMax = MovingMap[MinMax, data, Quantity[15, "Seconds"]]

Select[First@Normal@minMax, #[[2, 1]] >= 0 && #[[2, 2]] < 5 &]
(* {{23, {0, 3}}, {24, {0, 4}}, {25, {0, 4}}, {26, {0, 
   4}}, {27, {0, 4}}, {28, {0, 4}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Ms/Mr 172, the looks like exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[5]; list = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 400];
list[[##]] & /@ 
 Select[Split[
   Catenate@Position[list, n_ /; 3 < n < 7], #2 - #1 == 1 &], 
  Length@# == 5 &]
```